# side menu by jonkykong (library for ios swift 3) is not loading when swiped

Tags: ios, swift3

Im using this library https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu 
opening issue is not helping

When my app is first launched and I swipe from left to right to pop the side menu, i see black screen

when I choose menu item and it has child view controller, I go to that child controller, then I go back, then doing step 1 results in messy side menu- something clearly goes wrong.

Info: the blue background if the side menu is a UIimageView stretched all over the View, with aspect fill so I do not know how it is been showed as chunks of images
How could I fix it? thanks

screenshot of storyboard:

initial navigation controller http://joxi.net/eAOGGOVuPkBVAo

case with child view controllers http://joxi.ru/xAe66odUGXwPry

link to youtube video https://youtu.be/PRk-WsShGlM

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not setting up the menu properly programmatically. From the README:

```
let menuLeftNavigationController = UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController)
menuLeftNavigationController.leftSide = true
// UISideMenuNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController, so do any additional configuration 
// of it here like setting its viewControllers. If you're using storyboards, you'll want to do something like:
// let menuLeftNavigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftMenuNavigationController") as! UISideMenuNavigationController
SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController = menuLeftNavigationController
```